# Finding all notes that have no tags in Evernote?

Tags: evernote

Is there some way to create a saved search that shows all notes that don't have any tags assigned?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create a customised search using the following syntax;

-tag:

This runs a search for all notes but excludes any notes with any tags. If you want a search for all notes with tags, simply omit the beginning '-'.

Comment: This only works for me in the Windows desktop app.  If I try it in Android or in the web app it returns every note, with and without tags.

Comment: Found a slightly different string that works across all platforms: -tag:**